# Is there an accredited doctorate in gastronomy?

Tags: phd, research-process

Can someone do research and eventually obtain a PhD in a gastronomy-related field (not approached from the side of chemistry, history or culture but rather from the culinary side) from an accredited university?

Comment: Google first answer: http://www.food-culture.org/food-studies-programs/ gave me 6 maybe relevant links (with Ph.D. in them).

Comment: At first I thought this was concerning a PhD in gastroenterology, and was curious why you wouldn't pursue the MD route. Cary on.

Comment: Thank you, @Zenon. The schools listed offer programs focused more on food chemistry, biochemistry or dietetics. I'm looking for more like a PhD (or rather, a DLA) for chefs program, which focuses on the more artistic view of cooking like flavours and textures (but not strictly from the chemists' point of view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the programs/universities mentioned in [the link](http://www.food-culture.org/food-studies-programs/) which Zenon gave in a comment, it appears that you may need to tweak a molecular gastronomy program to fit your interests. The Italian [University of Gastronomic Sciences](http://www.unisg.it/en/) looks to have several programs that might fit your desired focus.

Comment: Thank you, molecular gastronomy is indeed what I was thinking of (I just didn't know that was its proper name).